# useEffect spamming requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**State**

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

**checkIfUserIsEnabled()**

```
 async function checkIfUserIsEnabled() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/users/finduserbytoken?id=" + 
    getTokenIdFromURL);
    res.json()
   .then(res => setUser(res))
   .catch(err => setErrors(err));
}
```

**useEffect** When i call my `checkIfUserIsEnabled()` in the useEffect below it gets rendered once and displays the false version in the return method.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL);
        checkIfUserIsEnabled();
        return () => {
            /* cleanup */
        };
    }, [/* input */])`
```

**useEffect (2th)** If i do it like this instead, it keeps spamming the requests towards my API and displays true.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        checkIfUserIsEnabled();
      });
```

**Return**

```
    return (
        <div className="emailVerificationWrapper">
        {user.enabled 
            ? <h1>Thank you for registrating, {user.firstName}. Account is verified!</h1> 
            : <h1>Attempting to verify account...</h1>}
        </div>
    )
```

**To my question(s):** Why does the second useEffect spam the request? and is there a way i can make the request being rendered every ~2-3 second instead of the spam? and could i make it stop doing the request once it actually returns true?

Comment: You should definitely avoid setting state inside useEffect because it will trigger a new render

Comment: It's a very common use case to set state inside `useEffect`.

Comment: You can put checkIfUserIsEnabled in a useCallback but I don't know where getTokenIdFromURL comes from and how many times that changes reference. In your second effect just use setInterval to check every couple of seconds, just make sure the dependencies of your second effect don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect hook runs when the component mounts but also when the component updates. Because we are setting the state after every data fetch, the component updates and the effect runs again.

It fetches the data again and again. That's a bug and needs to be avoided. We only want to fetch data when the component mounts. That's why you can provide an empty array(or something which doesn't change) as second argument to the effect hook to avoid activating it on component updates(or only when that parameter changes) but only for the mounting of the component.

```
let URL = `http://localhost:8080/users/finduserbytoken?id=`;
async function checkIfUserIsEnabled() {
  const res = await fetch(`$(URL)` + 
    getTokenIdFromURL);
    res.json()
   .then(res => {setUser(res); return Promise.resolve()})
   .catch(err =>  {setErrors(err); return Promise.reject()});
}
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
 const abortController = new AbortController();
    const fetchData = async() => await checkIfUserIsEnabled();
    fetchData();

  return () => {
    abortController.abort();
  };
  }, [URL]);
```

Comment: This renders the return before my state gets populated causing the result to always be false. If i reload the page it gets rendered to true. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are setting the State, right?after it fetches the user... You can make a simple state check inside the return of render

Comment: With that check , if you userid changes from null to some ID, it will cause your render to run again, hope you know that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    checkIfUserIsEnabled();
}); <-- no dependency
```

As your `useEffect` doesn't have any dependency it will run on every render, so every time you change some state and your component re-renders it will send requests.